# Nested views in tabs binding to separate ViewModel

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Is there a way how to provide a nested view it's own viewmodel?

Example:
Master view of type TabbedView has multiple tabs.

```
<mvx:MvxTabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="Foo.Core.Pages.Access.MainPage"
                     xmlns:res="clr-namespace:Foo.Core.Resources;assembly=Foo.Core"
                     xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
                     xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Foo.Core.Pages.Access">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <views:LoginPage></views:LoginPage>
        <views:RegisterPage></views:RegisterPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</mvx:MvxTabbedPage>
```

The `LoginPage` and `RegisterPage` are in separate views. But all the binding must be in the MainViewModel and I want the bindings to be separately in the `LoginViewModel` and `RegisterViewModel`.

Is there a way how to setup the binding to the properties to appropriate viewmodel? Preferably in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

In order that to work you need to let the `NavigationService` (and therefore the `Presenter`) to load the children pages:

[Xamarin.Forms View Presenter -> MvxTabbedPagePresentationAttribute](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/xamarin.forms/xamarin-forms-view-presenter?scroll=606#mvxtabbedpagepresentationattribute)

In your case it should be something like:

**ViewModels**

```
public class MyTabsContainerViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public MyTabsContainerViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(navigationService));
    }


    public override async void ViewAppearing()
    {
        await ShowInitialViewModels();
        base.ViewAppearing();
    }

    private async Task ShowInitialViewModels()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<LoginViewModel>());
        tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<RegisterViewModel>());
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
}

public class RegisterViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
}
```

**Views**

*MyTabsContainerPage.xaml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<views:MvxTabbedPage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:MyTabsContainerViewModel" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Foo.Core.ViewModels;assembly=Foo.Core"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             x:Class="Foo.Core.Pages.Access.MyTabsContainerPage">

</views:MvxTabbedPage>
```

*MyTabsContainerPage.xaml.cs*

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(Position = MasterDetailPosition.Detail, NoHistory = true)]
public partial class MyTabsContainerPage : MvxTabbedPage<MyTabsContainerViewModel>
{
    public MyTabsContainerPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

*LoginPage.xaml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxContentPage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:LoginViewModel" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Foo.Core.ViewModels;assembly=Foo.Core"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             x:Class="Foo.Core.Pages.Access.MixedNavTab1Page">

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="This is Tab 1" />
        </StackLayout>

</views:MvxContentPage>
```

*LoginPage.xaml.cs*

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = false, Title = "LoginTab1")]
public partial class LoginPage : MvxContentPage<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

*RegisterPage.xaml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxContentPage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:RegisterViewModel" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Foo.Core.ViewModels;assembly=Foo.Core"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             x:Class="Foo.Core.Pages.Access.RegisterPage">

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="This is Tab 2" />
        </StackLayout>

</views:MvxContentPage>
```

*RegisterPage.xaml.cs*

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = false, Title = "RegisterTab2")]
public partial class RegisterPage : MvxContentPage<RegisterViewModel>
{
    public RegisterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Full sample in the [Playground project](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/bd3a438f8acff76657a743da0669d97254b7aaa6/Projects/Playground)
HIH